# Why the following is a seminorm rather than a norm

Tags: analysis, functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations

I really don't understand why the following is a seminorm rather than a norm?
$$
p_k(u)=\sum_{|α|\le k}\sup_{x∈R^n}(1+|x|^2)^{k/2}|D^α u(x)|, 
$$
for all $u \in C^\infty$.

I do understand if $|α|>0$, then $p_k(u)$ has to be a seminorm because of the example $u(x)=$constant.

(This staff is about tempered distributions. See Michael Taylor's book "Partial differential equations I").

I can't figure it out. I has been blocked by this for a while and I don't know what I am missing. Hoping for your answers, thanks.

Comment: I think you want the functions in that class to die rather fast. So constant functions dont belong to that class.

Comment: yes, you are right. But $p_k$ still can't just be a seminorm, it should be exact the norm. but all the books say it is just a seminorm. I still don't know why.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$p_k$ is only real valued for functions $u\in\mathscr S$ (Schwartz' space of rapidly decreasing smooth functions). However, restricted to that space $p_k$ is indeed a *norm* since for all $x\in \mathbb R^n$ you have $$|u(x)|\le (1+|x|^2)^{k/2} |D^0u(x)| \le p_k(u).$$

The reason for calling it nevertheless a *seminorm* is probably that the general theory of locally convex spaces in made with seminorms.

Comment: Thank you. It's very useful. But you mean if $p_k$ is not restricted in $C^\infty$ or $S$ (Schwartz' space), it could be just a seminorm such as locally cinvex spaces, right?

Comment: No, if $p_k$ is not restricted to $\mathscr S$ you get an "extended real valued norm" that is, it has the properties of a norm but takes the value $+\infty$.

Comment: Yes, I see. Thank you. But I still don't understand the meaning of what you are saying "The reason for calling it nevertheless a seminorm is probably that the general theory of locally convex spaces in made with seminorms."

Comment: One might define a *locally convex space* (l.c.s.) as a vector space together with a directed family of seminorms. If you want to describe a concrete l.c.s. you then have to give the vector space (in our case $\mathscr S$) and the family of seminorms (in our case the sequence $p_k$). That the family might have additional properties (like being true norms) is an extra condition (which, of course, can be useful but is not essential for having a l.c.s.).

Comment: Many thanks. I understand now. Thank you.